# Form - Redirect after hitting Submit

Tags: php, forms

I am looking to get my form to redirect after the submit button is pressed.. but I am not sure what I am doing in correctly.

```
<?php


$user_id = example;
$game_id = 'example';
$value = $_POST['value'];
$date = date(mdyHis);
$secret = "example";
$username = $_POST['username'];
$hash = md5($user_id.$username.$game_id.$value.$date.$secret);
$redeem_link="http://www.example.com/".$user_id."&userNAME=".$username."&gameID=".$game_id."&value=".$value."&dateTime=".$date."&key1=".$hash;

if($_POST['submit']){
    header( 'Location: ".$redeem_link."' ) ;
} 

?>
```

And here is my form code.

```
<form action='?' method='post'> 
<td>
<center>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Enter Username">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="password" name="value" placeholder="Enter Amount">
</div>
</tr>
<tr><td><center><button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" action="" type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'>Submit</button></center></td></tr>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line you should look at is: `header( 'Location: ".$redeem_link."' ) ;`

It should be: `header( 'Location: ' . $redeem_link ) ;`

Essentially, your code states, `Location: ".http://www.example.com/."`, which is not what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will make this as resolved answer after 12 minutes time :D

Answer (score 0):

There are two correct forms that works:

USE

```
header("location: " . $redeem_link );
```

OR

```
header("Location:$redeem_link ");
```

Best Regards